# Timer speeding up in Java

Tags: java, timer, delay

I know there are other questions about this, but none of them seem to help me to solve my problem. In my game, there is a Player that shoots a Missile, that fly towards negative y until it disappears out of the screen, going back to its original place and waiting to be shot again. However, every time the Missile is shot, it gets faster, like the delay in the Timer() gets shorter. The code:

Main class:

```
public class ShooterGame extends JFrame{
    static int playerX=500;
    static int playerY=520;

    InputHandler input = new InputHandler(this);
    public static Player player = new Player(playerX,playerY,50,50);

    public static void main(String[] args){
        ShooterGame game = new ShooterGame();
        game.run();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    static int windowWidth = 1300;
    static int windowHeight = 600;
    static int fps = 30;
    public static BufferedImage backBuffer = new BufferedImage(windowWidth, windowHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    public static Graphics bbg;

    public void run(){
        boolean running = true;

        initialize();

        while(running){
            long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

            update();
            draw();

            time = (1000 / fps) - (System.currentTimeMillis() - time);

            if (time > 0) { 
                try{ 
                    Thread.sleep(time); 
                } 
                    catch(Exception e){}; 
            };
        }

    }

    public void initialize(){
        setTitle("--- Shooter Game ---");
        setSize(windowWidth, windowHeight);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void update(){
        player.update(input);
    }

    public void draw(){

        Graphics g = getGraphics(); 

        Graphics bbg = backBuffer.getGraphics(); 

        bbg.setColor(Color.BLACK); 
        bbg.fillRect(0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight); 
        player.Draw(bbg);
        enemie1.Draw(bbg,10,100);

        if(game.player.Player.missileRunning) game.player.Player.missile.Draw(bbg);

        g.drawImage(backBuffer, 0, 0, this); 
    }

    public static Graphics getMainGraphics(){
        return bbg;
    }
}
```

Player class:

```
public class Player{

    private BufferedImage sprite;
    public BufferedImage missileSprite;
    public int x, y, width, height;
    private int fixedX;
    private final double speed = 5.0d;
    public static Missile missile;
    public static boolean missileRunning = false;
    public static boolean missileReady = true;

    public Player(int x, int y, int width, int height){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        missile = new Missile(this.x);

        try{
            URL url = this.getClass().getResource("ship.png");
            sprite = ImageIO.read(url);
        } catch(IOException e){}

        try{
            URL url2 = this.getClass().getResource("missile.png");
            missileSprite = ImageIO.read(url2);
        } catch(IOException e){}
    }

    public void keyPlayer(double delta, InputHandler i){
        if(i.isKeyDown(KeyEvent.VK_D)){
            if(this.x>=1240) return;
            else this.x+=speed*delta;
        }

        if(i.isKeyDown(KeyEvent.VK_A)){
            if(this.x<=0) return;
            else this.x-=speed*delta;
        }

        if(i.isKeyDown(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE)){
            if(missileReady){ 
                try {
                    AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("C:/Users/Gabriel/Desktop/Programacao/Other/java/ShootGame/game/player/Fire.wav").getAbsoluteFile());
                    Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
                    clip.open(audioInputStream);
                    clip.start();
                } catch(Exception ex) {
                    System.out.println("Error with playing sound.");
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                missile.x=this.x + 20;
                missileRunning=true; 
            }
        }

    }

    public void update(InputHandler inputP){
        keyPlayer(2.0, inputP);
        updateMissile(game.ShooterGame.backBuffer.getGraphics());
    }

    public void updateMissile(Graphics g){
        if(missileRunning){ 
            missileReady=false;
            missile.update(g);
        }
    }

    public Rectangle missileBounds(){
        return new Rectangle(missile.x, game.player.Missile.y, 6, 18);
    }

    public void Draw(Graphics a){
        a.drawImage(sprite,x,y,width,height,null);
    }

    public Rectangle getBounds(){
        return new Rectangle(x,y,width,height);
    }
}
```

Missile class:

```
public class Missile{

    public BufferedImage sprite;
    public static int x;
    public static int y=504;
    private int interval = 2000;
    private Timer timer2;
    private boolean isAlive = game.player.Player.missileRunning;
    static final AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger();
    public static boolean timerReady;

    public Missile(int x){

        this.x=x;
        this.y=504;
        this.sprite=sprite;

        try{
            URL url = this.getClass().getResource("missile.png");
            sprite = ImageIO.read(url);
        } catch(IOException e){System.out.println("Error loading image");}  
    }

    public void Draw(Graphics g){
        g.drawImage(sprite,x,this.y,6,18,null);
    }

    public void update(Graphics g){ //The problem
        if(game.player.Player.missileRunning==true){
            timerReady=true;
            if(checkTimer()){
                timer2 = new Timer();
                timer2.schedule(new Move(), 0, interval);
            }
            this.y = y;
            if(y <= 0){
                game.player.Player.missileRunning=false;
                timerReady=false;
                y=504;
                if(!checkTimer()){
                    timer2.cancel(); 
                    timer2.purge();
                }
                timer2=null;
                reload();
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean checkTimer(){
        if(timerReady){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    class Move extends TimerTask{
        public void run(){
            int keeper = 3;
            if(keeper>0) y-=interval/1000;
        }
    }

    public synchronized void reload(){
        Timer missileBetween = new Timer();

        missileBetween.cancel();
        missileBetween = new Timer();

        TimerTask readyMissile = new TimerTask(){
            public void run(){
                game.player.Player.missileReady=true;
            }
        };

        missileBetween.schedule(readyMissile, 20);
    }

    public static int getNumber(){
        return count.get();
    }

    public static AtomicInteger getAtomic(){
        return count;
    }

}
```

*(I am not posting all my program, just the parts that matter for the question)*
*(If anything is missing, please say it)*

Thanks

Comment: Why are you creating a `Timer` when this functionality should be maintained by the main loop?

Comment: You're scheduling a new task (on a new timer) each time you fire a missile, but the old ones are still running.

Comment: I do not mean to be misunterstood, but what is the main loop?

Comment: `timerReady=true;` then `if(checkTimer()){` doesn't look suspicious to you?

Comment: The `run` method of `ShooterGame` is the main loop, it should be responsible for updating the game state, painting the game state and maintaining the frame count...

Comment: @immibis I thought the timer.cancel() and timer.purge() would solve this problem. Do these statement work as I want them to?

Comment: Just a note: You have `int keeper = 3; if(keeper>0) y-=interval/1000;` Why are you testing if 3 is larger than 0?

Comment: @MadProgrammer `timerReady=true` and the if(checkTimer) statements are just a failed try to solve my problem, they should not be there but they will not change anything(I expect)

Comment: @gabzerbinato Do you know what `new` does?

Comment: @PM77-1 The same thing with `timerReady`

Comment: Regardless, you should NOT have a `Timer` or other `loop` involved, the trigger to update the current state should come from the main-loop, it should be telling the entities to update themselves and modifier there states accordingly, the main-loop would then paint that state...

Comment: @immibis So should I, instead of using `new` every time, I should "reset" my timer?

Comment: @gabzerbinato You didn't answer it... Do you know what `new` does?

Comment: @immibis It creates a new instance of the specified class, am I wrong?

Comment: @gabzerbinato You're not wrong. So what does `Timer missileBetween = new Timer(); missileBetween.cancel();` do? It creates a new Timer, then cancels it. Which doesn't do anything because *that* Timer (that was just created) doesn't have any tasks scheduled, so there's nothing to cancel.

Comment: @immibis You are right, thanks for pointing out that for me, but are you saying the delay is caused by a massive creation of `missileBetween` timers?

Comment: @gabzerbinato No. Look at Missile.update. Your program creates a Timer, and scheduling a Move object (so `Move.run` is called every `interval` milliseconds). Then, a bit later, your program does the same thing again - create a new Timer, and schedule a Move object (so now `Move.run` is called every `interval` ms, and it's called another time every `interval` ms - you asked for it to happen twice, so it happens twice). Then the next time `Missile.update` is called, you schedule it again (so now it happens three times every `interval` ms) and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without running the code...

```
timerReady=true;
if(checkTimer()){
    timer2 = new Timer();
    timer2.schedule(new Move(), 0, interval);
}
```

Basically means that `checkTimer` will ALWAYS return `true`, meaning that each time that `update` is called, you are creating ANOTHER `Timer`, which is probably creating a few dozen timers, all updating the game state independently...which will cause the object to speed up...

This kind of logic and functionality should be controlled by the main-loop.  On each cycle, you should check the state of the object and make a decision to move or remove it, there should be no other "timers" or "loops" involved here...

Oh, and learn to do without `static`, it will cause you more issues then it will solve in this case.

And...

```
Timer missileBetween = new Timer();
missileBetween.cancel();
missileBetween = new Timer();
```

...is pointless, you create a local `Timer`, cancel it, even though it's not actually, running, create a new, local instance and schedule some task...

You lose the reference to the local version and can no longer be modified...

Comment: Thanks MadProgrammer, I will now use my main loop.

Answer (score -1):

The time you are sleeping in the `ShooterGame.run()` method is wrong. Instead of `time = (1000 / fps) - (System.currentTimeMillis() - time);` why not simply `time = 1000/fps`.

First time you enter the `while` loop in run `time` will be approximately `1000/fps` because there is little time between the two method calls. Future cycles through run will give you a negative number (System.currentTimeMillis() is a big number compared to 1000/fps) which means you will not call `Thread.sleep(time)`. Set a break point there and tell us if this is correct.

Comment: I corrected my code as you said, but my Player is now flicking on the screen

Comment: I don't know what flicking on the screen is but reading the code the time variable was being set to a negative number. Was this the case? If so and you are having other issue then there are probably other problems in the code. I stopped at the first error I could see.

Comment: Actually your answer did not answer my main problem, and by "flicking on the screen" I mean my Player is quickly disappearing and appearing again, and moving like if it was in a lagged game

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be more help, but if you still want to pursue this approach instead of MadProgrammers then I'd suggest you look at why is clearing the display. Changing the period between sleeps shouldn't change the behavior you had from moving fast to flickering on screen. I can understand going slow though. Before you weren't sleeping at all between update/draw calls but now you are.

Comment: So if I change the sleep time to be shorter my player will not be lagged anymore? (Of course depending on how much shorter)

Comment: I assume so, try setting it to zero to prove it yourself. This should give you the same behavior you were getting before. It still wont solve your problem of the player momentarily disappearing between sleeps. It will just be less noticeable.

Comment: You're welcome :).
That's why it's always good to solve problems in small steps instead of large redesigns until you fully grasp the situation.